# How to indicate error bars on the legend symbols in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am transitioning to using `pgfplots` to do most of my plots these days, however I am not always able to get the plots looking as I want them to.

I am plotting some data points with error bars, and it would be great if I could get the legend to reflect this, e.g. similar to the ones produced by gnuplot. Here is basically what I want vs what I have (`gnuplot` on left, `pgfplots` on right)

what I want -> [image: Gnuplot style legend]
what I get -> [image: pgfplots legend]

And the mandatory MWE basically copied from the manual but with a legend

```latex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis} [
        legend style={
          at={(0.05,0.95)}, anchor=north west
        },
      ]
        \addplot+ [
          only marks,
          error bars/.cd,
            y dir=both, y fixed=0.1,
        ]
        coordinates {
          (0,0)
          (0.1,0.1)
          (0.2,0.2)
          (0.5,0.5)
          (1,1)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Data}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I would assume it is possible to do this with `\addlegendimage` but I am not fluent enough in `pgfplots` to find out how to automatise this process for every node style.

Edit: Here is the result from compiling the MWE for future reference

[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! The MWE really does not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the documentclass, fixed

Comment: You should probably use `\documentclass{article}`  see _http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided_

Comment: Thanks, I have actually never used the minimal class before, it just felt appropriate for the question as it doesn't really have anything to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: The problem with `minimal` is that people copy code from TeX.SE, so questions and answers with it are actually somewhat of a land mine.  It is a complete disaster when used,  by anyone other than an real expert, in a LaTeX document that has any text.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the heads up, I will keep it in mind in the future :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to distinguish the legend drawing you can use the `legend image post style` which appends additional options to only the legend but not to the plot itself. And if `only marks` is given to a plot you can override it back via `sharp plot`. For the error bar notation you can use the `|` arrow head.

Hence you can just add the following to your axis options

```
legend image post style={sharp plot,|-|}
```

and it gives

[image]

If these don't satisfy your specs then you can basically draw your own legend image via `legend image code` explained in the manual.

Comment: @JonasGlesaaen My pleasure.